# Get Current Git branch name in Danger Js script

Tags: git, danger

I am writing a custom danger js check in danger js.
I want to avoid running this check when the branch is a hotfix/* branch

I want to know how to get the current branch name in the javascript scope in which the dangerfile.js file runs.

I've read the [danger.systems documentation](https://danger.systems/js/reference.html#GitHubUtilsDSL) but nothing is mentioned about the branch name.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will give you the branch name

```
import { danger } from 'danger';
console.log('### branch: ',  danger.github.pr.head.ref)
```

This is from `GitHubMergeRef` (from node_modules/danger/distribution/danger.d.ts) which has this comment:

```
  /**
   * The reference point for the merge, e.g. "master"
   */
  ref: string
```

If you do want to find out more info, just do a `console.log('### pr: ',  danger.github.pr)` and search for your branch name in the results. (when doing a: npx danger pr https://github.com/org-name/repo-name/pull/2282)

Comment: Not sure how a label refers to the branch. Can you explain?

Comment: I actually found out the `ref` is more specific. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update and your feedback. Good catch! `danger.github.pr.head.ref` (as stated below) should do the trick I guess. Let's see.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a documentation gap, see https://github.com/danger/danger-js/issues/1078 - maybe you would like to add another comment there.

I found this archived [danger-plugin-dangerfile-builder](https://%20https://github.com/sogame/danger-plugin-dangerfile-builder/blob/master/docs/utilities.md) - it mentionds some shorthands:

> **targetBranch**
> Branch name where the pull request will be merged into (shorthand for **danger.github.pr.base.ref**).
>
> **sourceBranch**
> Branch name where the pull request is being send from (shorthand for **danger.github.pr.head.ref**).

I am not sure if this helps, maybe you can scan the code yourself.

Try `danger.github.pr.base.ref` and/or `danger.github.pr.head.ref`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `danger.github.branch_for_head`, as mentioned here:
https://danger.systems/reference.html